# Calculate radial velocity

Tags: math, lua, physics

I am trying to simulate noise-filtering in a Doppler-shift radar. It should filter out objects moving below 25 m/s relative to the radar (approaching or moving away). There should be two ways of avoiding detection by the radar: if the object is moving in any direction but at a speed below 25 m/s OR moving at any speed but perpendicular to (or rather, circling) the radar. In both these cases the object's radial velocity relative to the stationary radar should be below 25 m/s and thus fool the radar into filtering it out as noise. I know the objects position and velocity vector (2D and 3D). I am a complete idiot when it comes to math so I just cant get my head around this. Any help please?

Edit: Badly formed question. I want to get the true radial velocity relative to the radar and filter objects that are moving faster than 25 m/s but in a relative heading that would make the radial velocity towards the radar less than 25 m/s. One example would maybe be an object moving at 30 m/s and 45 degrees perpendicular to the radar would be filtered out but not if the object was moving at 300 m/s.

Comment: Here you are, I've edited your question with the proper term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know any Lua, but since this is a purely mathematical question, mathematical pseudo-code should be enough.

Let `r` be the position of the radar, `x` be the position of the object, and `v` be the object's velocity vector (in units of metres per second). All of these are two- or three-dimensional vectors, depending on whether you're working in two or three dimensions.

The velocity condition is pretty easy: Just take the [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Euclidean_norm) of the velocity vector `v` and compare it against your threshold of 25 m/s.

To find out whether the object is circling the radar, compute the vector from the radar to the object, which is `x-r`, and check whether it is perpendicular to the velocity vector; you do this by computing the [scalar product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_product), which becomes zero when the two vectors are perpendicular. In practice you would use a small threshold greater than zero to allow the two vectors to be slightly non-perpendicular.

In pseduo-code, this becomes:

```
if v.norm()<25 or v.scalar_product(x-r)<0.05
    Ignore object
end
```

You'll have to find out how to compute [norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Euclidean_norm) and [scalar products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_product) in Lua (or, failing that, compute them yourself as described in the linked pages).

**Answer to edited question (closure velocity)**

The scalar product comes in handy for your modified question, too. You obtain the closure velocity as

```
v_closure = v.scalar_product(r-x)/norm(r-x)
```

Note that the result is signed -- positive if the object is moving towards the radar, negative if it's moving away from it. You would then do your noise filtering check like this:

```
if abs(v_closure)<25
    Ignore object
end
```

So in a sense this modified test is even simpler than the original version.

Comment: Wow! Very quick and good answer, but I think I stated my question wrong. What I was looking for is the true closure velocity. I want the radar to filter out an object that is moving at 26 m/s and 89 degrees perpendicular (which should be a closure velocity of something below 1 m/s i think) and not filter out an object that is moving at 1000 m/s and 89 degrees perpendicular to the radar. Same thing for an object that is moving at 30 m/s and 30 degree off from straight to the radar should be filtered out but not an object moving 30 m/s but only 1 degree off from straight to the radar.

Comment: @RagnarDa I've edited the answer to show how you can compute closure velocity.

Comment: Thank you! This was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by Martin, but just an aside and a possible simplification, considering you have to calculate Cos(Theta) anyway, wouldn't it be just as easy to simplify to

v_closure = norm(v)Cos(Theta)

Where Theta is the angle between the the vectors (r-x) and v